# Flutter issue: multiple widgets used the same global key

Tags: flutter

I have a constants file:

```
class GlobalKeyConstants {
  static GlobalKey countriesVisitedKey = GlobalKey(
    debugLabel: 'countriesVisitedKey',
  );
  static GlobalKey countriesUnlockedKey = GlobalKey(
    debugLabel: 'countriesUnlockedKey',
  );
}
```

now inside `HomePage` widget I have:

```
Widget getCarousel() {
    List<Widget> items = getCarouselItems(context);

    return Column(
      children: [
        CarouselSlider(
            carouselController: carouselController,
            options: CarouselOptions(
              height: 300.0.h,
              viewportFraction: 0.9,
              onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
                setState(() {
                  currentIndex = index;
                });
              },
              pageSnapping: false,
            ),
            items: items.map((i) {
              return Builder(
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return Container(
                    width: 300.w,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
                    child: i,
                  );
                },
              );
            }).toList()),
        ....
      ],
    );
  }


  share(GlobalKey key, BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      String path = await AchievementProvider().takeScreenshot(
        currentIndex == 0
            ? GlobalKeyConstants.countriesVisitedKey
            : GlobalKeyConstants.countriesUnlockedKey,
      );
      XFile file = XFile(path);
      await Share.shareXFiles([file]);
    } catch (e) {
      if (context.mounted) {
        showErrorSnackbar(context, e.toString());
      }
    }
  }

  List<Widget> getCarouselItems(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> items = [];

    items.add(
      RepaintBoundary(
        key: GlobalKeyConstants.countriesVisitedKey,
        child: const CountriesVisitedCard(borderRadius: 8),
      ),
    );
    items.add(
      RepaintBoundary(
        key: GlobalKeyConstants.countriesUnlockedKey,
        child: CountriesUnlockedCard(borderRadius: 8),
      ),
    );

    return items;
  }
```

I need the RepaintBoundary for taking screenshot of the widget. As you can see I am using two different keys for `CountriesVisitedCard` and `CountriesUnlockedCard`

But I am still getting:

```
Reloaded 5 of 3283 libraries in 479ms (compile: 107 ms, reload: 139 ms, reassemble: 213 ms).

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey.
```

The Card widgets themselves does not have usage of GlobalKey nor do they have any. Why am I still getting error even though I am using two different keys?

Usage of getCarousel:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return items();
  }

  Widget items() {
    return Consumer<AchievementProvider>(
      builder: (context, provider, _) {
        return Stack(
          children: [
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                getCarousel(),
                getButtons(context),
              ],
            ),
            provider.isLoading
                ? Container(
                    width: 300.w,
                    height: 300.w,
                    color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                    child: const Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    ),
                  )
                : const SizedBox.shrink(),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

issue persists even if I comment out adding one widget to the `List<Widget> items`. I can confirm that the GlobalKeys are not used anywhere else in the app.

Comment: How do you call `getCarousel`? Where do you use it?

Comment: inside a column which is inside a Stack

Comment: No, you have to include the code. Or at least a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The cause of the error might be in the place you didn't even realize.

Comment: alright done. Added usage of getCarousel

Comment: Ok you don't use the global keys anywhere but are you sure you're not declaring the global key in the constructor with a value key?